# How do I add an android pop screen in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an android project with unity3D now.
I want to pop a small screen when I touch the button on the screen like the image below.
How could I implement this?
(My reputation is too low to post the picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SoLr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your popup with [GUILabels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) and GUITextures. Create an empty gameobject called Popup, and place all these gameobjects under its hierarchy, and disable it in the inspector.

Make a new script attached to the button. In this script, create a public GameObject variable for your popup called popUp, and create a new function called OnMouseDown().

Within this function place the code

popUp.SetActive(true);

Finally, in the inspector, drag and drop the disabled gameobejct into the popup variable of your script, and it should work as you want.

Comment: thanks!could I add a black background on it?